# C# и SQL Compact Edition

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, исключения, datagridview

Работаю с программой, которая включает в себя базу данных SQL Compact Edition 4.0. Также имеется DataGridView, в который информация с базы данных закачивается и отображается, с этим проблем нет. Проблема в сохранении изменений из DataGridView в саму базу данных, в особенности при исполнении команды dA.Update(dataT) на предпоследней строке.

Код прилагается:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Adminka : Form
{
    public Adminka()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DataTable dataT;
    BindingSource bindS;

    private void Adminka_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection yourConnection = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnection))
        {
            dataT = new DataTable();
            bindS = new BindingSource();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM AdminTest";
            SqlCeDataAdapter dA = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, yourConnection);
            SqlCeCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dA);
            dA.Fill(dataT);

            bindS.DataSource = dataT;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindS;
        }
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnection))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM AdminTest";
            SqlCeDataAdapter dA = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, con);

            SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dA);

            DataTable dataT = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

            dA.Update(dataT);
            MessageBox.Show("Информация о пользователях была успешно обновлена", "Обновление Данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Вылезает вот такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что в `dataGridView1.DataSource` лежит `DataTable`? Вот здесь `dataGridView1.DataSource = bindS;` вы записали туда `BindingSource`. Соответственно при несовпадении типов операция `as` возвращает `null`.